# Badges clip on mobile website on Chrome on Android 6

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, mobile-web

I was going though the mobile site today on Chrome after my phone upgraded to Android 6 and noticed some oddities with the tags. All the tags appear to be clipped on their right side and a little on the top as shown below.

[image: screen shot]

The exact phone I have is a Samsung Galaxy 5.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, Chrome 51 (just FYI).

Comment: could you check again) we've pushed some fixes for mobile views, so it might be fixed now.

Comment: @Pawel it's fixed now. Thanks.